# Windows Phone 8: Load png from gallery

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, png, windows-phone, gallery

I want to load png files (with transparency) from the Windows Phone photo gallery. At the moment I am using the PhotoChooserTask. But the problem is, that even if the image is a png, I am getting back image data without transparency. When I look at the png files in the Windows Phone Gallery app then transparency is correct.

Are there means to load png files with transparency from the gallery?

Regards,

Comment: Have you used the `MediaLibrary` to get access to all the pictures, you can [get the byte stream of an image that way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.picture.getimage.aspx)?

Comment: Actually I am using the returned byte stream as a source for a BitmapImage. And this resulting BitmapImage does not show the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the answer is no.  If the image didn't have transparency in it before you cannot add it.

Also (as you have discovered) you only get back an image stream from the media library not the original file itself and the stream only contains the colour data with no transparency.

Best option (if the user uses skydrive) is to use the Live/SkyDrive API to download images from the users backups or from the web.

Alternatively if you are doing a camera app, have a look at the lenses API or the Nokia Imaging SDK